# Dormant debugging directive UNIX Shell Script

Tags: shell

First time today i got to know about `$DBG_SH  # dormant debugging directive (Apr. 92 column)` someone used in the shell script. I search around the globe but did not get the exact answer, how and why it is used.

[Here is the link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.emacs/JsmTn1L32xI).

> Its Just Being Used at the top of the script as, which i tested now and looks as it gives every bits of Information you are doing at the base code level , here i'm adding and deleting the entries via `ldapmodify` command and it gives all information what it is does at the background without debugger.

```
#!/bin/sh
$DBG_SH
flags="-v"
case $1 in
"live") # Live server
  LDAPSERVER=ldapprod
  ADMIN="uid=bason,ou=people,o=real.com"
  pass=""
  ;;
"dev") # test system
  LDAPSERVER=ldapdev
  ADMIN="uid=bason,ou=people,o=real.com"
  pass=""
 ;;
*)
  echo "Usage: $0 live|dev [ldif filename] [cont]"
  echo "       live|dev      - specify live or dev server"
  echo "       ldif filename - specify filename containing ldif"
  echo "       cont          - continue on error"
  exit 1 ;;
esac

if [ ! -f "$2" ];then
  /bin/echo -n "Path to LDIF file: "
  read PATH_TO_LDIF
else
  PATH_TO_LDIF="$2"
fi
if [ "$3" = "cont" ];then
  flags="$flags -c"
fi
if [ `uname -s` = "Linux" ];then
  flags="$flags -x"
fi
if [ -z "$pass" ]; then
  /bin/echo -n "Password: "
  read -s pass
  echo
fi

ldapmodify $flags -h $LDAPSERVER -D "$ADMIN" -w $pass -f $PATH_TO_LDIF
exit $?
```

Comment: It mostly isn't used — I've not seen it in use.  It allows you to use `DBG_SH='echo Hello' mainscript` and the script will echo 'Hello' at the point where `$DBG_SH` appears.  You can substitute more useful commands there, in theory.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, thnx for your inputs .. i have Just tested it and it gives nice code level information which a command doing via shell script.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is not used much. However, if you run your script in some environment having `DBG_SH` set to some [`set` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#The-Set-Builtin) you could have some debugging output.

Think of something like `env DBG_SH='set -xv' yourscript.sh`

Comment: Basile, thnx for your input , i have Just tested it and it gives nice code level information which a command doing via shell script.  i have updated the post as well.

Answer (score 2):

I'd steer clear of it. If you wanted to find documentation for it, I think you'd have to spelunk through the old Bourne shell code.

Typically, `/bin/sh` is hard linked to `/bin/bash`, and bash has checks to verify that it's invoked as `sh` to run in POSIX mode. bash has newer facilities for debugging, especially check `man bash` for `trap` and `set`.

So I'd avoid this one because:

1. you're rarely writing scripts for old versions of Bourne
2. if the feature is "dormant" it's deprecated, and
3. your actual shell is usually bash and will not support obscure / deprecated features in Bourne.

That said, it might be worth it to poke around the old Bourne code to see how old Unix utilities were written back then, just as a learning experience.

Comment: thnx for your input , i have Just tested it and it gives nice code level information which a command doing via shell script.